# When a site uses @font-face is that font stored locally?

Tags: css, fonts

Here's something that has been bugging me... I am currently creating an application for an international corporation (naturally I won't name them) and they use a specific non standard font for promotional material. I've asked them to supply this so I can use it in my application and they're taking forever to get back to me (I asked weeks ago and a deadline is pending). I've noticed on all of their websites they use this same font and incorporate it using the @font-face feature.

Now the sneaky part of me wondered could I take the font their using within the @font-face and install it on my machine so I could finish my work. However then the worried part of me remembered that I have used @font-face for other clients and naturally there are distribution issues with such fonts (they're property of the client and not for public use). I really wouldn't want people to be able to install or distribute these.

Is it possible for someone to take the font's I've used for previous site when incorporating @font-face. If these are available to visitors of my sites can I prevent their download?

Perhaps this is something I should lose sleep over...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your worry should be "are these font files accessible and downloadable over http?"

The answer is yes.  A web developer can open your CSS file, look at the URL/Filename and download the files to reuse.  And I don't believe there's much you could do about stopping the downloads for reuse.

Answer (score 2):

As kishu27 mentioned in his answer (+1 from me), your @font-face fonts are free for the taking (not free to use, depending on licence) an here's a source to back that up:

> Although it is now technically possible to embed almost any font
>   inside a web page, it is important to remember that if you use a
>   commercial font for this purpose, you must have a license to do this.
>   Since putting a font on a website will allow anyone on the Web to
>   download it, a lot of font foundries currently do not allow their
>   fonts to be used for web page embedding. It is for this reason that
>   the browser vendors have been reluctant to implement this technology
>   into their products until recently (font embedding is part of the CSS2
>   specification, which has been around since 1998

Source: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2009/09/20/font-face-in-depth/